# I am looking for a PHP equivalent to the rs.MoveNext I use in ASP

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have only been using PHP for about a week (and even though I have been using ASP for 12 years I am by no means an expert) so please bear with me on this...I am trying to convert my Classic ASP website to PHP.  So far I have been able to find answers to most of my problems but I am stuck on this one.

**I am looking for a PHP equivalent to the .MoveNext function I use in ASP.**

In the example, I have a table with about 450 records and while I want them all to be displayed, I only want there to be 100 per column.  It might not be great code but it works for me.

```
set rsSpecial = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
'Grab all the Supporters Names and Website URLs Order by Name
rsSpecial.Open "SELECT sName, sURL FROM gktwspcf ORDER BY sName ASC", conn
    if not rsSpecial.EOF then
        sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "<table width=" & Chr(34) & "98%" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbCrLf
        Do
            i=0
            sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "<td valign=" & Chr(34) & "top" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbCrLf
            sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "<p>" & vbCrLf
            Do
                if rsSpecial("sURL") <> "" Then
                    sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "<a href='"& Replace(rsSpecial("sURL"), "&", "&amp;") & "' target=" & Chr(34) & "_blank" & Chr(34) & ">"
                    sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "" & Replace(rsSpecial("sName"), "&", "&amp;") & ""
                    sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "</a>"
                    sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "<br>" & vbCrLF
                        'Otherwise just list their name
                else
                    sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "" & Replace(rsSpecial("sName"), "&", "&amp;") & ""
                    sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "<br>" & vbCrLF
                end if
                i=i+1
                rsSpecial.MoveNext
            Loop Until i=100 or rsSpecial.EOF
            sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "</td>" & vbCrLf
        Loop Until rsSpecial.EOF
        sSpecialFriends = sSpecialFriends & "</table>" & vbCrLf
    end if
rsSpecial.Close
Set rsSpecial=Nothing
```

I can't seem to find a good example of how to recreate a nested loop in PHP where I can move to the next record.  This is what I have so far - and it displays each record, 100 times, 100 columns wide.  **I think I need to find somewhere to insert the PHP equivalent of a MoveNext.**

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT sName, sURL FROM gktw_spcFriends ORDER BY sName ASC", $con) or die(mysql_error()); 
$sSpecialFriends = "";
if (mysql_num_rows($result))
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    { 
    $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends."<table width=".Chr(34)."98%".Chr(34).">" ."\n";
        do
        {
            $i=0;
            $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends."<td valign=".Chr(34)."top".Chr(34).">" ."\n";
            $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends."<p>" ."\n";
                do
                {
                    //Check for URL
                    if ($row['sURL'] != "")
                    {                                               
                        $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends . "<a href='". str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['sURL']) . "' target=" . Chr(34) . "_blank" . Chr(34) . ">"."\n";
                        $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends . "" . str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['sName']) . "" ."\n";
                        $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends . "</a>" ."\n";
                        $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends . "<br>" ."\n";
                    }
                    //Otherwise just list their name
                    else
                    {
                        $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends . "" . str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['sName']) . "" ."\n";
                        $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends . "<br>" ."\n";
                    }
                    $i=$i+1;
                }
                while ($i<100);
            $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends . "</td>" ."\n";
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    $sSpecialFriends = $sSpecialFriends . "</table>" ."\n";
    }

mysql_close($con);
```

So, if anyone can help me with a PHP equivalent to ASP's MoveNext and/or the best way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` ?

Comment: Is that an answer, comment or question?

Comment: Sorry i thought it would be obvious... and I'm too lazy to write a proper answer. `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` gets the next record and assign's it to `$row` which is probably what you need.

Comment: Sorry, it probably is obvious to someone who has been doing this for longer than a week (and has any talent).  I just wasn't sure where to put it.  It works, thank you for your help.

Comment: My assumption was that this is your code, and since you already found out how to get the next row in the recordset, i could just point it out.

Comment: Well, I have pieced this together from examples and trial and error...I am just trying to figure out all the idiosyncrasies between ASP and PHP.  I thought that $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); retrieved a record but did not know it was like ASP's moveNext and would get the next row each time you called it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Matt. Unless you are using an ADODB library, PHP doesn't really work like that. The following PHP script loops through records like MOVENEXT would have done:

```
// Get all the data from the "example" table

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th> </tr>";

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['age'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($dbConn);
```

However, if you are using an ADODB library, you can still use MOVENEXT and EOF like this:

```
$rs = $db->Execute($sql); 
if ($rs) 
    while (!$rs->EOF) { 
        ProcessArray($rs->fields);     
        $rs->MoveNext(); 
    }
```

I'd recommend using the top version, much simpler.